# How to take a string from a TextView and convert to double without app crashing?

Tags: android

I'm working on a calculator app right now, and I'm trying to take the two string values from two different TextViews and convert them to doubles, so I can do operations on them. The problem is that when I'm trying to cast the strings as doubles, it isn't working, and will crash the app. I tried it in a try catch block, and it has a NumberFormatException every time. Here are the lines that aren't working properly:

```
    double doubleContents1 = Double.parseDouble(stringContents1);
// convert first value from string to double
    double doubleContents2 = Double.parseDouble(stringContents2);
// convert second value from string to double
```

Here is the full code:

```
public void sendMessageEquals(View view) {
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    // this is the first textview, for the first number
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    // second textview for the second number
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    // third textview for displaying the result from the first two
        String stringContents1 = (String) textView2.getText();
    // get the value from the first textview
        String stringContents2 = (String) textView3.getText();
    // get the value from the second textview
        double doubleContents1 = Double.parseDouble(stringContents1);
    // convert first value from string to double
        double doubleContents2 = Double.parseDouble(stringContents2);
    // convert second value from string to double

        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            Double doubleContents3 = doubleContents1 + doubleContents2;
            String stringContents3 = Double.toString(doubleContents3);
            textView4.setText(stringContents3);
            state = "Phase1";
        }
        else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            Double doubleContents3 = doubleContents1 - doubleContents2;
            String stringContents3 = Double.toString(doubleContents3);
        }
        else if (operator.equals("*")) {
            Double doubleContents3 = doubleContents1 * doubleContents2;
            String stringContents3 = Double.toString(doubleContents3);
        }
        else if (operator.equals("/")) {
            if (doubleContents2 != 0) {
                Double doubleContents3 = doubleContents1 / doubleContents2;
                String stringContents3 = Double.toString(doubleContents3);
            }

        }
        else {
            state = "Phase1";
        }

    }
```

logcat:

```
04-23 00:28:50.804 20868-20868/com.example.kellen.homework2tester D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-23 00:28:50.805 20868-20868/com.example.kellen.homework2tester E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kellen.homework2tester, PID: 20868
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "operand 1: 1"
        at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
        at com.example.kellen.homework2tester.MainActivity.sendMessageEquals(MainActivity.java:184)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Post your logcat

Comment: Catch that exception and see exactly when are you trying to parse invalid double type? Maybe it's an empty string, maybe contains comma instead of dot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logcat exception says that your string is "**operand 1:**" , so it can't be parsed to a `Double`.
You should take the value from your `EditText` and not from the `TextView`.

Comment: Yeah your right. In my example that i used 
(In my app), it worked for me with an EditText

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Do I need to completely change my TextView to be an EditText?

Comment: That should be easy. Change the type in XML and in java. You can type things in it so it should make things a lot easier for you. Note that i **may** not be right

Comment: I am not the person who posted this answer so I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar example in my application. This it what worked for me:

```
 double doubleContents1 = Double.parseDouble(textView2.getText().toString());

 double doubleContents2 = Double.parseDouble(textView2.getText().toString());
```

If this dosent help, post your logcat by editing your question so we can take a look at this error

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, I went ahead and posted the errors from logcat.